# How to define keymap for minor mode correctly

Tags: emacs, elisp, minor-mode

I'd like to define custom mode for improvements that suits to any program mode. And I need to define key-bindings for all this modes. I choose to use `define-minor-mode` with `:keymap` to declare key bindings with minimum effort.

I'd like to bind `comment-or-uncomment-region` to `"C-;"` The kbd macro gave me `[67108923]` magic number for this key sequence.

I've wrote sample that doesn't work

```
(define-minor-mode
  my-mode
  nil nil
 :keymap '(
   ( [67108923] . comment-or-uncomment-region )
  )
)
```

I've registered mode, toggled it on, but pressing `С-;` produces notifications that the key sequence is not defined

After that I've wrote in the scratch buffer and evaluate simple `global-set-key` that performed in expected way.

```
(global-set-key [67108923] 'comment-or-uncomment-region )
```

Now pressing `C-;` produces expected `comment-or-oncomment-region` behavior.

I've tried to debug the issue with searching to function info via `C-h f`. It produces strange output, `comment-or-oncomment-region` is bound *twice* to *different* key sequences:

```
It is bound to C - ;, C-;
```

First one appears and disappears with the minor mode toggling, other emerge from `global-set-key` invocation.

How can it be, if I've used the same key definition for both maps? What details I have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Just create a keymap normally, using `make-sparse-keymap`, and name it `my-mode-map` --- you're done. No need for `:keymap` arg to `define-minor-mode`.
2. Or use the keymap you create using `make-sparse-keymap` as the value of `:keymap`, if you like. (But no need to, since it is named as the minor mode expects: `my-mode-map`.)
3. But why not just use a global binding, via `global-set-key`?  Why do you even need this to be a minor-mode binding?

Comment: make-sparse-keymap worked perfectly, but I still don't understand what is wrong with the original approach based on http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Minor-Modes.html

Comment: ayvango: Your code works in Emacs 24.3. I suspect your problem was that you got it wrong initially, after which `my-mode-map` was defined. Any subsequent evaluations would not have clobbered the existing map; you would have needed to unbind `my-mode-map` first.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the magic number.  IOW use `[?\C-\;]`, so it can be understood by humans.
And I agree with Drew:

```
(defvar my-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map [?\C-\;] 'comment-or-uncomment-region)
    map))

(define-minor-mode my-mode
  "blabla"
  nil nil nil
  <add code, if any>)
```

Oh, and one more thing: why would you prefer `C-;` over the standard `M-;` binding?